# trimming of white spaces before values

Tags: vba, excel

I am having an issue trimming white space characters. When I enter a value and give spaces before and after the value in Excel, I see spaces surrounding it but I should not see those extra spaces.

I would like to remove these spaces but I'm not sure how to achieve this, here is the output that I'm getting currently:

```
ServerName = "       testing     "
```

but the generated output should be like this...

```
ServerName = "testing"
```

---

Here is the code that I'm using in my project:

```
If Sheets(Itm).Cells(i, 2) = "Required1" Then
    MsgBox "Enter the value for required field : " & Sheets(Itm).Cells(i, 1)
    Return
End If

Value = Replace(Sheets(Itm).Cells(i, 4).Value, vbLf, " ")
'Value = Sheets(Itm).Cells(i, 4).Value
```

Comment: Do not use tags that are not relevant to your question. VB.NET is not VBA, VB6 etc...

Comment: Did you try `Trim` or `Application.WorksheetFunction.Clean`?

Comment: Value = Replace(Sheets(Itm).Cells(i, 4).Value, vbLf, "") instead of Value = Replace(Sheets(Itm).Cells(i, 4).Value, vbLf, " ")

Comment: I've removed all that markdown from your question, please only use un-ordered lists to provide brief points of detail, not as line breaks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (Untested)

```
Value = Trim(Sheets(Itm).Cells(i, 4).Value)
Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Clean(Value)
Print #1, Sheets(Itm).Cells(i, 1) & "=" & Value
```

Here is a sample code to understand how it works...

```
Sub sample()
    Dim sample As String

    sample = "Sid"

    Debug.Print Len(sample) '<~~ This will give you 3

    sample = " " & vbNewLine & sample & vbNewLine & vbCrLf & vbLf

    Debug.Print Len(sample) '<~~ This will give you 11

    sample = Trim(sample)

    Debug.Print Len(sample) '<~~ This will give you 10

    sample = Application.WorksheetFunction.Clean(sample)

    Debug.Print Len(sample)  '<~~ This will give you 3
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for your email, can you update in my code its confusing

Comment: What email? And what is confusing about what I posted above?

Comment: can you tell me where to add the code, sorry it was thanks for reply not email

Comment: Replace the line `Value = Replace(Sheets(Itm).Cells(i, 4).Value, vbLf, " ")` with the 3 lines that i have given in my above post.

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
Print #1, Sheets(Itm).Cells(i, 1) & "=" & Value
```

With:

```
Print #1, Replace(Sheets(Itm).Cells(i, 1) & "=" & Value," ","")
```

Comment: if that space is not actually a space but a special character then this code will not work as intended :)